# Control sprite animation with a slider

Tags: javascript, css, animation, slider

```js
var $slider = $("#slider");
var $target = $(".animation");
var cols = 30;
var rows = 1;
var gridWidth = $target.width();
var gridHeight = $target.height();
var interval = 1; //for testing



var tl = new TimelineLite({onUpdate:updateSlider});
var count = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
  for (c = 0; c < cols; c++){
     var xpos = -c * gridWidth;
     var ypos = -r * gridHeight;
    tl.set($target, {backgroundPosition: xpos + "px " +  ypos + "px"}, count * interval);
    count++;
  }
}

//add some additional time so that the last box can be seen
tl.set({}, {}, count*interval)


//--- SLIDER ---
$slider.slider({
  range: false,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 0.02,
  value:0,
  slide: function ( event, ui ) {
    tl.progress( ui.value / 100).pause();
  }
});
function updateSlider() {
    $slider.slider("value", tl.progress()  * 100);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:20px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.sheet {
  margin:20px;
  width:30vw;
  height:30vw;
  background:url(https://i.ibb.co/r79LYcS/card.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.animation {
  width:30vw;
  height:30vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Spritesheet grid rows cols</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h3>animation</h3>
<div class="sheet animation"></div>
<div id="slider" style="width:300px;"></div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Short question. I've got a sprite animation (approximately 40 square pictures). I really need to connect it with a slider, so that a visitor could control this animation with it. The only example I found doesn't work for me - https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/NqWqzQ/.

Script from this example:

```
var $slider = $("#slider");
var $target = $(".animation");
var cols = 3;
var rows = 3;
var gridWidth = $target.width();
var gridHeight = $target.height();
var interval = 0.5; //for testing



var tl = new TimelineLite({onUpdate:updateSlider});
var count = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
  for (c = 0; c < cols; c++){ 
     var xpos = -c * gridWidth;
     var ypos = -r * gridHeight;
    tl.set($target, {backgroundPosition: xpos + "px " +  ypos + "px"}, count * interval);
    count++;
  }
}

//add some additional time so that the last box can be seen
tl.set({}, {}, count*interval)


//--- SLIDER ---
$slider.slider({
  range: false,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 0.02,
  value:0,
  slide: function ( event, ui ) {
    tl.progress( ui.value / 100).pause();
    
  }
});
function updateSlider() {
    $slider.slider("value", tl.progress()  * 100);
}
```

May someone, please, show me another example or give a hint of how to do that?

Comment: There are other js files needed, click on the cog in the js panel and you will see the other js files

Comment: Oh, no, it's not that it doesn't work. It does! But it's just not responsive enough. Even though I tried to use VW and background-size, something wrong happens to the sprite sheet and I don't know why( Also, when I'm trying to change the amount of colons in script, it starts to slide a bit during scrolling

Comment: You are going to need to edit the question to add more detail as to exactly what is not working for you and what the expected result would be. It would be best if you can demonstrate the issue in a short example, there is snippet button that you can use to create and ran the code on here

Comment: Thank you! I added the snippet. As you can see, it slides to the right a bit when you move the slider, although I think I didn't change anything wrong in the code. Also, when you try to change browser window size -- everything breaks